# powershell.exe -ex bypass -command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a working powershell script, i Need to convert the entire script to run in single line of code with **powershell.exe -ex bypass -command ....**

The reason in the background is script should not run as .ps1 file instead i can run as single command. Am looking help in this... am quite new to powershell..but tried to manage the script below.. i need to convert it to run from command as single line of code..

```
    # Config
$logFileName = "Application" # Add Name of the Logfile (System, Application, etc)
$path = "c:\Intel\" # Add Path, needs to end with a backsplash

# do not edit
$exportFileName = $logFileName + (get-date -f yyyyMMdd) + ".evt"
$logFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile | Where-Object {$_.logfilename -eq $logFileName}
$logFile.backupeventlog($path + $exportFileName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `-ex` (short for `-ExecutionPolicy`) if you're not using a file, because it only applies to files.

To make it one line, you basically replace newlines with `;`.

But `-Command` isn't the best idea for this. You're going to have to be careful about properly escaping all the quotes and pipes throughout your code.

You can look into `-EncodedCommand`, whereby you Base64 encode your code, and pass it all as one string.

If you check `powershell.exe /?` it has an example at the bottom:

> ```
> # To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
> $command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
> $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
> $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
> powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
> ```

If you could explain more about your reasons for not wanting to use a file, it may be helpful in getting answers that are more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I actually checked the help but in this case not clear on making such a big line one to one line script..

Comment: @Huntsman if you use `-EncodedCommand` you don't need the original script to be on one line anymore. You don't need to escape any characters. You just Base64 encode the entire file, then the encoded result will be one big line.